# Plotting infinite sum with Bessel function and generalized G-function

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

How can I plot this function with sum of Bessel functions
\begin{aligned} \tau (r,t)&= gt \biggl(\frac{r}{R} \biggr)^{2}+ \frac{2g}{\lambda ^{\eta }R} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{J_{2}(rr_{{n}})}{r_{{n}}J_{1}(Rr_{{n}})}\sum_{\ell =0}^{\infty } \biggl( \frac{-\nu r_{n}^{2}}{ \lambda ^{\eta }} \biggr)^{\ell } \\ &\quad {}\times\bigl[G_{\eta , -\ell -2,\ell +1} \bigl({-\lambda ^{-\eta }},t \bigr)+ \lambda ^{\eta }G_{\eta , \eta -\ell -2,\ell +1} \bigl({-\lambda ^{- \eta }},t \bigr) \bigr] \end{aligned}
where the generalized G-function is
$$\begin{aligned} &G_{\ell , \jmath , \zeta }(\sigma ,t) \\ &\quad = L^{-1} \biggl\{ \frac{s^{ \jmath }}{(s^{\ell }-\sigma )^{\zeta }} \biggr\} \\ &\quad =\sum_{i=0}^{\infty }\frac{\sigma ^{i} \varGamma (\zeta +i)}{\varGamma ( \zeta )\varGamma (i+1)} \frac{t^{(\zeta +i)\ell -\jmath -1}}{\varGamma [( \zeta +i)\ell -\jmath ]} ;\quad \operatorname{Re}(\ell \zeta -\jmath )>0, \operatorname{Re}(s)>0, \biggl\vert \frac{\sigma }{s^{\ell }} \biggr\vert < 1. \end{aligned}$$

and $J_{2}(\cdot)$ represents the second order Bessel function of the first kind, and $r_{{n}}$ are the positive roots of $J_{2}(Rr_{{n}})=0$.
In Mathematica

````
G[q_, v_, r_, a_, t_] := 
  Sum[(Pochhammer[r, j]*a^j*t^((r + j)*q - v - 1))/(Gamma[1 + j]*
      Gamma[(r + j)*q - v]), {j, 0, Infinity}]; 
general[r_, t_] = 
  g*t*(r/R)^2 + ((2*g)/(\[Lambda]^\[Eta]*R))*
    Sum[(BesselJ[2, 
         r*Subscript[r, n]]/(Subscript[r, n]*
          BesselJ[1, R*Subscript[r, n]]))*
             
      Sum[(((-\[Nu])*(((4*n - 1)*Pi)/(4*R))^2)/\[Lambda]^\[Eta])^
         l*(G[\[Eta], -l - 2, l + 1, -\[Lambda]^(-\[Eta]), 
           t] + \[Lambda]^\[Eta]*
           G[\[Eta], \[Eta] - l - 2, l + 1, -\[Lambda]^(-\[Eta]), t]), 
               {l, 0, Infinity}], {n, 1, Infinity}]; 
```
````

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Please take a look at functions [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html), [`MeijerG`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeijerG.html), [`BesselJ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BesselJ.html), [`BesselJZero`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BesselJZero.html), [`Sum`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html) ... then type your function in Mathematica code and include this in your question.

Comment: The generalized G-function can be expressed by **FoxH** function.

Comment: g ,R and another parameters is not defined ?

Comment: take R=1, g=2, $\nu =0.001$, $\eta =0.001$, $\lambda =10$, $\rho =800$. As g is a constant, R>r>0,  $0\leq \eta < 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code is very slow. Compiling my code probably speed-up increasing.

I don't have compiler on my Hardware.

```
ClearAll["`*"]; Remove["`*"];

 M = 10;(*M = infinity*)
 R = 1;
 g = 2;
 \[Nu] = 1/1000;
 \[Eta] = 1/1000;
 \[Lambda] = 10;

G[q_, v_, r_, a_, t_] := Sum[(Pochhammer[r, j]*a^j*t^((r + j)*q - v - 1))/(Gamma[1 + j]*Gamma[(r + j)*q - v]), {j, 0, M}];

rn[n_] := BesselJZero[2, n]/R(* The positive roots of: BesselJ[2,R*rn] = 0 *); 

general[r_, t_] := g*t*(r/R)^2 + (2*g)/(\[Lambda]^\[Eta]*R)*
Sum[BesselJ[2, 
   r*rn[n]]/(rn[n]*BesselJ[1, R*rn[n]])*(-\[Nu]*
    rn[n]^2/\[Lambda]^\[Eta])^
  l*(G[\[Eta], -l - 2, l + 1, -\[Lambda]^(-\[Eta]), 
    t] + \[Lambda]^\[Eta]*
    G[\[Eta], \[Eta] - l - 2, l + 1, -\[Lambda]^(-\[Eta]), 
     t]), {l, 0, M}, {n, 1, M}]

Plot3D[general[r, t], {r, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 2}](* Very very Slow!!!*)

ListPlot3D[Partition[Flatten[Table[{i, j, general[i, j]}, {i, 0, 2, 1/8}, {j, 0, 2, 
1/8}]], 3], PlotRange -> All](*A bit better.*)
```

The generalized G-function can be expressed by FoxH function.

```
Sum[(Pochhammer[r, j]*a^j*t^((r + j)*q - v - 1))/(Gamma[1 + j]*Gamma[(r + j)*q - v]), {j, 0, Infinity}] == 
t^(-1 + q r - v)/Gamma[r]*FoxH[{{{1 - r, 1}}, {}}, {{{0, 1}}, {{1 - (q r - v), q}}}, -a*t^q]
```

**FoxH** function in Mathematica is unusable for numeric calculation, it's just slow.